# Using CAST AS INTEGER in Expression in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been trying to use this query :

```
Select ((2017 - CAST(substring(p.nip from 9 for 4) AS INTEGER)) * 12) + 11 - CAST(substring(p.nip from 13 for 2) AS INTEGER) >= 144 from m_pegawai p
```

to no avail. I keep getting error `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""`

What's wrong with the query? I've tried to place parentheses in various places but no result so far.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you when we have absolutely no idea what `p.nip` is or what it contains, or what you're trying to do with that expression? *I have something (but I won't tell you what) and I'm trying to cast substrings of it as integers and it's not working. What's wrong?* When you ask a question here, remember we have absolutely no information about your problem other than the details you provide (or don't) to use to try to help you. If you don't include the relevant information, any attempt to answer would be a wild guess.

Comment: You can't cast empty string to integer. Either `substring(p.nip from 9 for 4)` or `substring(p.nip from 13 for 2)` return empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty string `''` is not a valid integer. Some databases let you cast `''` to `0`. PostgreSQL is not one of them.

Use

```
CAST (NULLIF(substring(...), '') AS INTEGER)
```

or for a SQL-standard method, use a `CASE` expression - but that's more verbose.

Comment: `""` should be `''`

Comment: Thanks. It turned out to be there's some `p.nip` values with length less than specified in the `substring(p.nip from 9 for 4)` or `substring(p.nip from 13 for 2)`